# How To Create An App That Allows For Profile Picture Upload/Change permanently

Tags: java, android

I want to allow users to upload a profile picture in my app so far I have achieved this, but the problem is when I exit the app the profile picture disappears, so I was asking is there a way to store the picture in cache I'm using glide but don't know how to go about it

changing load defaults on my oncreate method but still does not work.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
public static final int REQUEST_IMAGE = 100;

@BindView(R.id.img_profile)
ImageView imgProfile;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(null);

    loadProfileDefault();



}

private void loadProfile(String url) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Image cache path: " + url);

    GlideApp.with(this).load(url)
            .into(imgProfile);
    imgProfile.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this, android.R.color.transparent));
}

private void loadProfileDefault() {
    GlideApp.with(this).load(R.drawable.baseline_account_circle_black_48)
            .into(imgProfile);
    imgProfile.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.profile_default_tint));
}

@OnClick({R.id.img_plus, R.id.img_profile})
void onProfileImageClick() {
    Dexter.withActivity(this)
            .withPermissions(Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            .withListener(new MultiplePermissionsListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPermissionsChecked(MultiplePermissionsReport report) {
                    if (report.areAllPermissionsGranted()) {
                        showImagePickerOptions();
                    }

                    if (report.isAnyPermissionPermanentlyDenied()) {
                        showSettingsDialog();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(List<PermissionRequest> permissions, PermissionToken token) {
                    token.continuePermissionRequest();
                }
            }).check();
}

private void showImagePickerOptions() {
    ImagePickerActivity.showImagePickerOptions(this, new ImagePickerActivity.PickerOptionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTakeCameraSelected() {
            launchCameraIntent();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChooseGallerySelected() {
            launchGalleryIntent();
        }
    });
}

private void launchCameraIntent() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ImagePickerActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(ImagePickerActivity.INTENT_IMAGE_PICKER_OPTION, ImagePickerActivity.REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    // setting aspect ratio
    intent.putExtra(ImagePickerActivity.INTENT_LOCK_ASPECT_RATIO, true);
    intent.putExtra(ImagePickerActivity.INTENT_ASPECT_RATIO_X, 1); // 16x9, 1x1, 3:4, 3:2
    intent.putExtra(ImagePickerActivity.INTENT_ASPECT_RATIO_Y, 1);

    // setting maximum bitmap width and height
    intent.putExtra(ImagePickerActivity.INTENT_SET_BITMAP_MAX_WIDTH_HEIGHT, true);
    intent.putExtra(ImagePickerActivity.INTENT_BITMAP_MAX_WIDTH, 1000);
    intent.putExtra(ImagePickerActivity.INTENT_BITMAP_MAX_HEIGHT, 1000);

    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE);
}

private void launchGalleryIntent() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ImagePickerActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(ImagePickerActivity.INTENT_IMAGE_PICKER_OPTION, ImagePickerActivity.REQUEST_GALLERY_IMAGE);

    // setting aspect ratio
    intent.putExtra(ImagePickerActivity.INTENT_LOCK_ASPECT_RATIO, true);
    intent.putExtra(ImagePickerActivity.INTENT_ASPECT_RATIO_X, 1); // 16x9, 1x1, 3:4, 3:2
    intent.putExtra(ImagePickerActivity.INTENT_ASPECT_RATIO_Y, 1);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri uri = data.getParcelableExtra("path");
            try {

                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), uri);

                loadProfile(uri.toString());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want the selected image to remain even after closing the app how do I go about it please enter

Comment: Write the image to a directory and pass its URI to Glide to display it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways to achieve your result.

1. Using `Shared Preferences`. You can save your variable `uri` to shared preference and fetch data from it next time. For this, you can check if `uri` is available in `Shared Preference` or not.
2. Using `Room` database library.

Below is the code using `Shared Preference` :

Your `onCreate()` will be like :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(null);

    loadImageFromSharedPrefernce();
}

private void loadImageFromSharedPrefernce() {
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("PREF_NAME", MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (prefs.contains("imageUrl")){
            String imageUrl = prefs.getString("imageUrl", "");
            loadProfile(imageUrl);    //your method

        }
        else {
            loadProfileDefault();      //your method
        }

    }
```

Your `onActivityResult()` will be like :

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri uri = data.getParcelableExtra("path");
                try {
                    saveImageToSharedPreference(uri);
                    loadImageFromSharedPrefernce();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

private void saveImageToSharedPreference(Uri uri) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("PREF_NAME", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString("imageUrl", String.valueOf(uri));
        editor.apply();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should save profile pic URI in `SharedPreference` which is being received in `onActivityResult()` method. Adding the sample code below, have a look.

```
private void saveProfilePicLocal(String uri){
    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); // 0 - for private mode
    Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putString("profile_uri", uri); // Storing string
    editor.commit(); // commit changes
}
```

Now you have to call above function in onActivityResult() method like below.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri uri = data.getParcelableExtra("path");
            try {

                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), uri);
                saveProfilePicLocal(uri.toString())
                loadProfile(uri.toString());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After that, you should check whether you have any profile locally saved or not if there is any URI exists in SharedPreference read it and load otherwise load default one. Check the sample code below.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(null);

    //Check whether profile pic URI exists in Local SharedPreference
    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
if (prefs.contains("profile_uri")){
        String uri = pref.getString("profile_uri", null);
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(uri.trim())
          loadProfileDefault();
        else
          loadProfile(uri);
    }
}
```

Happy coding!.